# Compare String with other Pattern String

Tags: shell

In ShellScript , I want compare a string who contains a filename createad by user with a pattern filename string.

```
FILE1="image_custom001.jpg"

FILE2="image_custom02.jpg"

FILE_PATTERN="image_custom_xx.jpg"

IF (FILE1 == FILE_PATTERN) FALSE

IF (FILE2 == FILE_PATTERN) TRUE
```

I got this result by cutting the string in a various pieces and throwing in a great amount if/else. Is there an alternative and easy way to do this instead cutting the string?

Comment: What language/interpreter is this?

Comment: Think about moving this to codereview. Nevertheless you could very easy check for this with regular expressions ``/image_custom_\d{2}.jpg/``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "$var" | grep -q 'Item'
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
  echo"found it"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a unix shell, then you may try this:

```
{ echo "$file1" | grep -q '^image_custom_..\.jpg$'; } && echo ok
```

In place of the `echo ok`, you can put whatever action is needed when `$file` matches the grepped regular expression.